# Thunar sidebar looks different when opened from Google Chrome download page

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, thunar

I use Thunar as my File Manager. When I click "open downloads folder" from within the Google Chrome browser its sidebar looks different than when I open it normally (through the keyboard shortcut).

Normal Thunar:

[image]

Opened from Google Chrome download page:

[image]

How can I make them look exactly the same ?